# TDA7386 mounting

Tags: integrated-circuit, mount

I'm working on a little project to build an audio amplifier and I have everything ready except that I cannot figure out how to connect [TDA7386](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00000875.pdf) to the circuit. Is wire wrapping the only choice here? Or is there a simpler way to mount the chip? I would want to avoid soldering as much as possible since it's still within its prototyping stage.

It's this little guy here:

[image]

Comment: I added a link to the datasheet. Please make it a habit to do so in the future, so that we have all the data we need and therefore can  better answer your questions.

Comment: sorry about that... first time posting... Thanks to everybody who posted in such a timely manner... helped a lot...  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly meant to be soldered.  You said you want to avoid soldering, but your reason that you're still in the prototype stage doesn't make sense.  You don't say what this TDA7386 thing does nor did you provide a link, but if it's a audio power amp then it will need good solid power connectections at the very least.

I would solder it on the board along with everything else.  That way you can eliminate bad connections as one issue when you're testing the circuit.  It also lets you put bypass caps locally right where they are needed, have better all around signal integrety, etc.  Signal to noise ratio is a big issue with audio circuits, so for meaningful testing you should be using a layout and interconnect as close as possible to the final product.

Think about the cost too.  The time to wire warp this, connect all those little wires to the board, check it, deal with the resulting screwups anyway, deal with the questionable supply and ground and signals, all add up to more than adding the footprint to the boad and soldering this part.  Sooner or later you'll have to make the footprint and include it in your circuit, so doing it now doesn't cost any time in the long run.  In other words, putting everything on a board is *cheaper* than some flaky rigged up test circuit with flying leads all over the place.

### Added:

Now that the datasheet is available, I advise you even more strongly not to try wire wrapping this.  This is a power amp with significant currents.  Merely hooking up the amp is easy, but good layout is important.  You therefore want to test that in your very first prototype.  There will be enough current flowing around that ground offsets, crosstalk, and possibly even unstable operation due to unexpected feedback are all possibilities and things that need to be addressed by careful layout.

A sortof working circuit with wires all over the place won't tell much other than you hooked it up right, and that's the 1% problem.  At worst, the wire wrap version will have all sorts of problems, which will be quite different when you put this thing on a board.  Note the suggested layout section in the datasheet.  You don't usually see that for parts unless the layout is a important part of the design.

Comment: thank you very much, I have some quite ridiculous restrictions because of time restraint...  I will try to solder this if i can...  I just wondered if there's a better (easier) way to do this...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems wire-wrapping is the way to go. **But only because of your own restrictions**.

The IC's pinout isn't fit for breadboarding, and I also doubt you'll find a solder-free socket for it. But a self-designed PCB, or even floating soldered wiring will work. Both require soldering. Frankly, I don't see a prototyping stage as an objection for soldering. I've done prototyping all my life and it was always soldering, never wire-wrapping. Maybe you should explain first what you can solve with wire-wrapping in prototyping what soldering can't.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider working with something that is already built up as a module. There are a whole batch of vendors on eBay selling an audio amplifier module that uses a similar type chip. Search eBay using **TDA7297** as a search term and you will see things that look like this:

[image]

This type of module was suggested to someone else that needed an amplifier in another question on this site.

Comment: Note that the prices for these modules on eBay vary but are very reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could cram it into a ZIF Socket, which you could then breadboard.
[image: Zif Socket]

Comment: The pitch is 2 mm per row, and staggered. Length for first to last pin is 24 mm, which for the ZIF socket becomes 30 mm. Add a pin length of 3.5 mm for the shorter row, and it looks, er, difficult.

Comment: Yup-- I saw the "1" in the datasheet, for some odd reason, and read it for some reason as 0.1", not 1mm.  It looked DIP-like to me!

Comment: I decided you could "probably" [tm] rebend the pins so to sit either side of  a 0.3" centre to centre breadboard centre gap BUT as this involved rebending leads near the seal this did not seem a good thing to recommend to someone unfamiliar with such things.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually place this and similar packages into a breadboard if you really want.

The distance between the two rows of pins is 4 mm typical, which is the same as the inner width of the standard breadboard trench. If you deform the leads a little bit (say straighten the back column), you can plug them into a breadboard and have one column on each side of the board. I did that when I felt that I couldn't be bothered making a PCB for a L298N in Multiwatt15 package, which is very similar to Flexiwatt25 used by your chip.

The bad side of this is that if you want to use the standard PCB footprint, you'll have to move the pins back into original shape.